# How to integrate CDN in existing codeigniter Project

Tags: codeigniter, cdn, codeigniter-3

How to integrate content delivery network in existing codeigniter Application.
So that base-url needs to point main server and 
resource-url (like images, css, js etc) need to point cdn server.

All images are linked with absolute path like below

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url("media/images/image_name.jpg"); ?>" alt="StackOverflow" >
```

And the Result will be like below

```
<img src="http://example.com/media/images/image_name.jpg" alt="StackOverflow" >
```

Here i need to replace **example.com** with **cdn.example.com**.

Do i need to edit manually in all places?

Thanks for Helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to create one helper method like below

```
function cdn_base_url() {
    $url = base_url();
    if(is_cdn_integrated){
        $url = 'http://cdn.example.url.com/';
    }
    return $url;
}
```

And we need to call that method in view files like below instead of calling with `base_url().`

```
<img src="<?php echo cdn_base_url()."media/images/image_name.jpg"; ?>" alt="StackOverflow" >
```

Answer (score 0):

It is like normal call in view

e.g.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do I need to edit manually in all places.